# Getting Error while creating request XML using JAXB and sending the same to target URL to get response XML

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, spring-ws

I am using Spring and eclipse and trying the create a client code that uses the given XSD, creates the request XML and sends the same to target URL to get the response. I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:350)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:344)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:336)
    at com.elkay.client.EliteDevOrdCrClient.addOrder(EliteDevOrdCrClient.java:61)
    at com.elkay.client.EliteDevOrdCrClient.main(EliteDevOrdCrClient.java:75)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

Request XML is generated properly.

When I am trying the same with SOAPUI, I am able to get the desired response.

Please give some pointer, where I am going wrong.

TIA!

Comment: You're welcome, just go through the questions you've asked and [mark the answers that have helped you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) (and only one answer from each question can be accepted). I have seen your comments on specific answers to your questions, that have solved your problems. Start with those.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/39974-connection-refused-connect-any-help?p=368970#post368970)

> Well, it's quite simple, really: the service you're trying to connect
>   to is not running at the specified address. That's why it can't
>   connect.

Most probably your service is stopped by you or by some other process. To solve it simply start the service and try running the code again to access the webservice requests.

Else if your webservice is running in port 80 you may be accessing it using some other port. Configure the correct wsdl port to access the Webservice.